# Call servlets doGet() method with RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, servlets, requestdispatcher

How is it possible to call `doGet()` method from `RequestDispatcher`?

`RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/CartServlet");

        rd.forward(request, response);`

This code calls `doPost()` as the default action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It calls `doPost()` because your original request used POST method.
Generally servlets cannot "call" each other. They just can forward or redirect request. In both cases the same HTTP method that was used in original request is used.

If you want to call `doGet()` of other servlet it is the time to refactor your application, i.e. separate the logic implemented in `doGet()`, put it to other class and call this class from both servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Check out below link, using **HttpURLConnection** to  send request internally by POST or GET methods. I had felt the need for this for a long long time.

[Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)